# ggplot symbol size in exported pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm exporting my ggplot to a pdf file. The symbols are huge and when I change the symbol size in `geom_point` they do not change in the exported file. What should I do? I guess a bigger question is how could I ensure the size of everything I set up in ggplot (for example font size =12 pts) is exactly the same in the exported file?

Comment: What is the current way you are trying to save your ggplot to a pdf file? ggsave() should do the trick?

Comment: I think this in part depends on your pdf reader and how it renders fonts and vectors. Try saving to a raster image format like png and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: I use `ggsave` and saving to a raster image doesn't solve the problem. I can change `scale` in `ggsave` which does affect the output, but then I don't know the exact physical dimensions in the output.